# How to know which class is getting loaded by which class Loader in java?

Tags: java, classloader

Recently i was asked by a computer science professional to describe about the class loaders in Java. I explained him about 3 class loaders namely "BootStrap CL","Extension CL" and "Application CL", i also explained to him about "Deligation Algorithm". Next he asked me to prove it, can anyone give me a code to practically see the Classloaders in Execution?

Comment: If you do not want to answer, no need to downvote. You are not forced to answer. . .navigate to some other question !

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways you could go about this:

1. Show that different classes have different `ClassLoader` objects. For example, `YourMainClass.class.getClassLoader()` might be a `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader`, while `System.class.getClassLoader()` is null (as are other system classes). Here is a quick test:

   - Class from a JAR: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@2a139a55
   - Main class: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@2a139a55
   - `java.lang.System`'s classloader: null
   - System class loader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@2a139a55
   - System class loader's parent: sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@4aa298b7
   - Main class's classloader's parent: sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@4aa298b7
   - Jar class loader's parent: sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@4aa298b7

   The parent class loaders are used in the following way:

   1. A classloader recieves a request to load a class. If it already has it loaded, it returns it.
   2. That classloader first asks its parent to load it. If the parent cannot load it, then that classloader itself loads and returns it.
2. Show the OpenJDK source, and its multiple ClassLoaders.
3. Describe an application where this occurs in the real world. You could talk about scripting engines that define classes at runtime, servlet containers, certain build systems, etc, etc.

Comment: What does Null refers to ? Does that mean that Bootstrap Class loader loads the predefined class but since the Bootstrap Class loader is wrtten in Native language and not java while other 2 are java classes therefore it gives output as null while other 2 gives out put assun.misc.Launcher$ApplicationClassLoader ?

Comment: And how to test Extension Class loader ?

Comment: @Milind Yes, that appears to be correct. The bootstrap class loader doesn't appear to have a `ClassLoader` object but rather is part of the JVM's native code. It can't be written in Java since then there will be no classloader to load it and its dependencies.

Comment: @Milind Extension classes are stored in a JDK directory (presumably in Program Files/Java for Windows and `/usr/lib/jvm` for Linux), and are loaded by an extension class loader. See [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/load.html) for more info. if you want to test it, put a jar into the extensions folder and load a class from there.

Comment: Thanks it worked "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\jre\lib\ext" this is the path where i placed Jar file.